# Как правильно составить запрос на сортировку flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Имеется Модель, связанная отноешнием один к многим с другой моделью. Статья и комментарии
Article.query.first().comments - вернет InstrumentedList, имеющий доступ к len()
Нужно составить Article.query.order_by() с аргументом таким, чтоб получить последовательность отсортированную по кол-ву комментариев к статье. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    cut = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
        default=datetime.utcnow())

    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
        nullable=False)
    owner = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('owner', lazy=True))



    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('articles', lazy=True))

    comments = db.relationship('Comment', lazy=True,
        backref=db.backref('comments', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % self.id    


class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
        default=datetime.utcnow())

    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    owner = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('creater', lazy=True))

    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'))
    article = db.relationship('Article', backref=db.backref('article', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Comment %r' % self.id
```

Comment: было бы не плохо увидеть ваши модели

Comment: @5c0rp, добавил, взгляните

Comment: Что-то такое должно сработать 

`from sqlalchemy import func ... Article.query.outerjoin(Comment).group_by(Article.id).order_by(func.count(Comment.id).asc()).all()`

Comment: @AlexanderGoryushkin, спасибо огромное! Запрос сработал и сработал как надо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте join комментариев совместно c группировкой по `Article.id`, в качестве агрегатной функции для комментариев будет `count` - по получившемуся значению сортируются статьи.
Вы также можете изменить порядок сортировки поменяв `.asc()` на `.desc()`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

...

Article.query.outerjoin(Comment).group_by(Article.id).order_by(func.count(Comment.id).asc()).all()
```

Comment: спасибо тебе за помощь в решение задачки!